# Python threading gives "RuntimeError: can't start new thread"

Tags: python, pi-3b+

I have a raspberry pi 3b+. Im running this python code.

```
import time
import threading
from threading import Thread

def wait():
    time.sleep(5)

while 1:
    try:
        Thread(target=wait, name='test_thread').start()
    except RuntimeError as f:
        print(f'Failed at {len(threading.enumerate())} threads in.')
        print(str(f))
        break
```

It fails with the message `Failed at 249 threads in.
can't start new thread`

I am running a python program on my pi and i am aware of this issue. I want to increase the amount of threads it can handle to at least a couple thousand. Ive read somewhere that you could increase the stack size to help a bit but im not too sure. Does anybody know how I can run more threads?

Comment: I am interested to know why you want more than 250 threads, for a 4 core rpi.  If you like, you can setup a software stack, and swap threads between real and fake threads.  This way you can have one million threads.

Comment: Have a look at using a pool as per https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor and try setting the max_workers value BUT I bet you run out of memory or CPU before getting anything sensible done.

Comment: This is a general programming question and has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here. I think you would get quicker better answers at https://stackoverflow.com/